Left to Right Alpha-Beta Pruning (Same Child)

As can be seen, B and C share the same child node at G. After transversing from J-F-K-F-B-G-L-G-O-G, do I proceed straight to C to update beta or have to go through B and to A to temporarily update alpha, then back to C?
TLDR: Child node at G shares parent B and C, confused with the transversal order for alpha beta pruning in such cases.

FWIW, I've never seen alpha-beta pruning applied to anything other than trees.

This is too broad. You are asking about traversal order, about values for alpha, and about pruning. Stack Overflow is not for getting a review on your work, and a post should focus on one question only.

@trincot i dont know what the purpose of your comment is, doesnt help anyone here. If you can't answer it, then leave the questions to someone who can.

My comment is intended to help you make this into a post that fits the Stack Overflow guidelines, as otherwise this question risks to be closed, and that would be a pity. The points I raised are reasons why community members would vote to close this question. If you couldn't care less, then of course you can ignore my comment. I'm just a volunteer trying to help.
